# VB.NET Get Keys by sorted Values in Hashtable

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, hashtable

I am studying VB.NET and I want to know better idea to get Keys by sorted values in Hashtable

Here is my solution that I built

```
  Dim int_Value As Integer() = New Integer() {-9, 2, 8, 6, 8, 1, -9}
        Dim int_Key As Integer() = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
        Dim Dum_Int(int_Key.Length) As Integer

        Dim STORE_KEYS As New ArrayList
        Array.Copy(int_Value, Dum_Int, Dum_Int.Length - 1)
        Array.Sort(Dum_Int)
        Array.Reverse(Dum_Int)

        For I = 0 To Dum_Int.Length - 1
            For II = 0 To int_Value.Length - 1
                If Dum_Int(I) = int_Value(II) Then
                    STORE_KEYS.Add(int_Key(II))
                    int_Value(II) = Integer.MaxValue
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

I got output like..

> '' OUTPUT''
>
> - (0) 3 {Integer} Object
> - (1) 5 {Integer} Object
> - (2) 4 {Integer} Object
> - (3) 2 {Integer} Object
> - (4) 6 {Integer} Object
> - (5) 1 {Integer} Object
> - (6) 7 {Integer} Object

I assume that I have Hashtable.

I create two arrays and store both Keys (int_Key) and Values(Int_Value) From Hashtable

then I copy Value(Int_Value) array to Dum_Int to sort values

Whenever I found matching int value between Sorted Array and Original Value Array

I stored in to STORE_KEYS(arraylist) and I insert Max Int value to original array to prevent overlapping issue.

However, is there any way to improve this method ?

I don't believe that better sorting algor can't help to simplify this method.

Can you provide any hints to  simplify this method?

thanks

Comment: Unless you are using an earlier version of VB than 2005, you should not be using a `Hashtable` or an `ArrayList`.  You should be using a `Dictionary` and `List` instead.

Comment: I can't understand what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.Sort` method has an overload that will sort an array based on another array:

```
Dim keys = myHastable.Keys.Cast(Of Integer)().ToArray()
Dim values = myHastable.Values.Cast(Of Integer)().ToArray()

Array.Sort(values, keys)
```